# linux api rename behavior when new refer to an existing file

Tags: linux, api, rename

When I am reading the document for `rename` in the page https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename, i found the following

> If the link named by the new argument exists, it shall be removed and old renamed to new. In this case, a link named new shall remain visible to other processes throughout the renaming operation and refer either to the file referred to by new or old before the operation began. Write access permission is required for both the directory containing old and the directory containing new.

How should I understand the following

> refer either to the file referred to by new or old before the operation began

in this case a file with the same name with what `new` points exists, then after the rename operation, the `new` should points to either the `old` or the `new`. But the document says it is `before the operation began` which makes me confused.

How should I understand this? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

What this phrase means is that, during `rename`, the old `new` is replaced with the new `new` atomically.

What this means is that there is no point during the rename operation where trying to access `new` will result in a file not found error. Every access will result in either the old or the new `new` being returned.

After the `rename` is done (assuming it finished successfully), of course the new `new` will be referenced under that name.

This highlights `rename`'s usefulness in atomically replacing files. If you have a path containing some important file, and you need to update that file such that, no matter what happens, anyone any time that opens `/var/lib/important` will get either the old or the new version, this is the sequence of operations you need to do:

- Create an updated version of the file with the path `/var/lib/important.new`.
- Flush and close the `/var/lib/important.new`.
- `rename("/var/lib/important.new", "/var/lib/important");`
- Depending on your use case, flush `/var/lib`.

This guarantees that no matter what happens (process crash, power failures, kernel faults), either the old or the new file are available, complete and correct.

That last step (flushing the directory) is only necessary if you need to rely on it being the new version of the file that is available. If you do not do it, a power failure might cause the old file to re-appear after a restart. Typical uses don't bother with this step.